# How to select specific date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to select just 1st and 20th date in Oracle Database.
Here is my query.

```
SELECT INVOICE_DATE 
FROM invoice_debt@stilng1_lngrpt2 
WHERE INVOICE_DATE = TO_DATE('01', 'DD')
AND INVOICE_DATE = TO_DATE('20','DD')
AND INVOICE_DATE > TO_DATE('30-12-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
AND INVOICE_DATE IS NOT NULL GROUP BY INVOICE_DATE 
ORDER BY INVOICE_DATE DESC;
```

My query run this :

1. Select just 1st date
2. Select just 20th date
3. Select date > 30-12-2010

But nothing records returned.

I try using `EXTRACT` to get Day of DATE, but i cannot using `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE(INVOICE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY')) as DAY_EXTRACT 
FROM invoice_debt@stilng1_lngrpt2;
```

Please help me thank you.
:)

Comment: Check if the WHERE clauses you've used are indeed correct. A way to do that is remarking those clauses, and put part of it in the SELECT clause. Example : select invoice_date, TO_DATE('01', 'DD'), TO_DATE('20','DD') from ... and leave out the WHERE clauses relating to this value. -- The right part of that comparison is doubtful, as it will - in the best case - get the DD of current date, being sysdate. You don't reference any table column on the right side of the equal sign, and he does not assume any column, even if you out it on the other side (left side) of the equal sign.

Answer (score 4):

Use the OR condition for dates since you cannot have same invoice_date to be 1st day and 20th Day and also use to_char for the invoice date since to_date would return only one date

```
SELECT INVOICE_DATE 
FROM invoice_debt@stilng1_lngrpt2 
WHERE (to_char(INVOICE_DATE, 'DD')='01'
OR to_char(INVOICE_DATE,'DD')='20')
AND INVOICE_DATE > TO_DATE('30-12-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
AND INVOICE_DATE IS NOT NULL GROUP BY INVOICE_DATE 
ORDER BY INVOICE_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: That won't give desired output. The third condition should be AND to make sure the rows fetched are greater than the date value.

Comment: Thanks lalit I had overlooked

Answer (score 1):

> EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE(INVOICE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY'))

That makes no sense. You are converting a DATE to a DATE. I hope `INVOICE_DATE` column is **DATE data type**. So just extract the day from it -

`extract(day from INVOICE_DATE)`

You need an **OR** condition for the `1st/20th` day selection, and an **AND** condition to filter the dates with condition `TO_DATE('30-12-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`.

But, you need to make sure your query uses an efficient execution plan.

1. Using function **TO_CHAR** over the date coumn will suppress any **normal index** usage.

You need to have a **function-based index** on `to_char(INVOICE_DATE, 'DD')`

```
WHERE (to_char(INVOICE_DATE, 'DD')='01' 
         OR  to_char(INVOICE_DATE,'DD')='20')
      AND  INVOICE_DATE > TO_DATE('30-12-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
      AND  INVOICE_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

2. Since you only want to get dates greater than year `2010`, I think specifying a **RANGE** will use the index on the date column to go for a **INDEX RANGE SCAN**.

You could try these suggestions and examine the explain plan.